# Error Code: 1052. Column 'datetime' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

I have 15 tables of same column names and want to retrieve data on datetime condition but struggling to find out how to do this.

```
select * FROM AlbertstreetIN1,
AlbertstreetIN2,
AlbertstreetOUT1,
AshtonRPIN1,
AshtonRPIN2
WHERE datetime BETWEEN "2014-08-31 00:00:00" AND "2014-08-31 23:59:59";
```

data time is ambiguous for all the table names- error.

table format--
id,camera_id,name,plate,datetime, nationlilty,image_name,image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a column is ambiguous than it means more than one table in your query has a column with that name.

So you have to tell the DB which column you mean by adding the table name.

```
WHERE AlbertstreetIN1.datetime BETWEEN '2014-08-31 00:00:00' 
                                   AND '2014-08-31 23:59:59'
```

Don't know which table you want in your condition. I just chose one.

And you did not specify how to join your tables. They have to be linked somehow and you need to specify that in your query.

Otherwise you need to `union` them like this

```
select * FROM AlbertstreetIN1 WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2014-08-31 00:00:00' 
                                   AND '2014-08-31 23:59:59'
UNION ALL
select * FROM AlbertstreetIN2 WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2014-08-31 00:00:00' 
                                   AND '2014-08-31 23:59:59'
UNION ALL
select * FROM AlbertstreetOUT1 WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2014-08-31 00:00:00' 
                                   AND '2014-08-31 23:59:59'
UNION ALL
select * FROM AshtonRPIN1 WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2014-08-31 00:00:00' 
                                   AND '2014-08-31 23:59:59'
UNION ALL
select * FROM AshtonRPIN2WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2014-08-31 00:00:00' 
                                   AND '2014-08-31 23:59:59'
```

Comment: That's where I get the error I want to retreive all the tables not on one table

Comment: You did not add the join condition. Read up about joins to see how to do it.

Comment: I know that we can do that using joins but if these tables don't have any joins just independent tables.

Comment: Just to make sure can Inner joins on datetime col would work ?

Comment: that what i need .. thanks Juergen .. If  need to delete the data replacing delete on select would delete all the data.. right...

Comment: No, that won't work. You have to delete from each table seperately or define a join condition to delete from multiple.

Answer (score -1):

Use table name or alias name in where condition. Since `datetime` is present in more than one tables you can not use it in WHERE condition without table name or its alias.

like `AlbertstreetIN1.datetime`.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try like this?

datetime is a one of keyword / predefined in MYSQL

```
WHERE datetime BETWEEN "2014-08-31 00:00:00" AND "2014-08-31 23:59:59";
```

to

```
WHERE `datetime` BETWEEN "2014-08-31 00:00:00" AND "2014-08-31 23:59:59";
```

or smething like this

```
WHERE (AlbertstreetIN1.datetime BETWEEN "2014-08-31 00:00:00" AND "2014-08-31 23:59:59") || (AlbertstreetIN2.datetime BETWEEN "2014-08-31 00:00:00" AND "2014-08-31 23:59:59");
```