# Selecting multiple tables and displaying them ordered by datetime column

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime, phpmyadmin

I want to display the logs to recent activities page ordered by date. Now I was trying to execute this to my mysql

`"SELECT * FROM tracking_log.editlog, tracking_log.deletelog, tracking_log.loginlog, tracking_log.logoutlog ORDER BY time ASC";`

but it always says 
`Column 'time' in order clause is ambiguous`

all of the tables have a time column, format by datetime (0000-00-00 00:00:00)

How am I going to fetch them ordered by time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Specify your table name which the `time` belongs to. `ORDER BY tableName.time ASC`

Comment: "If a column is ambiguous than it means more than one table in your query has a column with that name." (с) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721307/error-code-1052-column-datetime-in-where-clause-is-ambiguous

Comment: All of them tables have time column. I want to fetch all those from 4 tables and sort them by time. How do I do that?

Comment: `SELECT 
* 
FROM tracking_log.editlog, tracking_log.deletelog, tracking_log.loginlog, tracking_log.logoutlog 
ORDER BY tracking_log.time ASC` try this if it works for you

Comment: @1000111 Unknown column 'tracking_log.time' in 'order clause'

Comment: Please try this: `SELECT 
* 
FROM tracking_log.editlog, tracking_log.deletelog, tracking_log.loginlog, tracking_log.logoutlog 
ORDER BY tracking_log.editlog.time ASC`

Comment: Show the table scheme and the real query (copy and paste).

Comment: And don't use evil `SELECT *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By which table's time column you want to order?

Assuming you want to order the result set by `tracking_log.editlog.time` column then the query would look like below:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM tracking_log.editlog, tracking_log.deletelog, 
     tracking_log.loginlog, tracking_log.logoutlog 
ORDER BY tracking_log.editlog.time ASC;
```

Just in case if all of the time columns in the respective table don't contain `NOT NULL` values at the same time then you need to use `COALESCE` I guess.

## Query using `COALESCE`

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM tracking_log.editlog, tracking_log.deletelog, 
     tracking_log.loginlog, tracking_log.logoutlog 
ORDER BY 
COALESCE(tracking_log.editlog.time , tracking_log.deletelog.time, tracking_log.loginlog.time,tracking_log.logoutlog.time)   ASC;
```

Comment: Hey it's working now! thank you. I just have to re-enter the url. lol Thanks!

Comment: So, which version you are using? with `coalesce` or without `coalesce`?

Answer (score 0):

'tracking_log' is your database name, and you're selecting multiple tables from that database, so you need to specify from which table you want to order 'time' by:

```
select * from tracking_log.editlog, tracking_log.deletelog ORDER BY tracking_log.editlog.time ASC
```

or whichever table from your database you want to use 'time' from.  This will fix the error but won't return any results because you have multiple tables in a SELECT clause without anything relating them together.

You'll need to specify some common columns on which you want to return results rather than getting the wildcard and then UNION the tables to aggregate the results.  For example, if you have common columns *userID*, *description* and *time* in all your tables, you could do the following:

```
(SELECT userID, description, time FROM tracking_log.editlog) 
UNION 
(SELECT userID, description, time FROM tracking_log.deletelog)
ORDER BY time
```

Comment: I tried it. no error but doesn't fetch anything from the database.

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM tracking_log.editlog, tracking_log.deletelog, tracking_log.loginlog, tracking_log.logoutlog ORDER BY tracking_log.loginlog.time ASC";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 for( $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++ ) {
  echo $row[$i];
 }`

Comment: The issue is now that you have multiple tables but no common point of reference for the tables that MYSQL can use to put all the data in a single row.  If you do "SELECT * from tracking_log.loginlog ORDER BY tracking_log.loginlog.time ASC" you will have results.  Is there a common field or id that you can use to relate the tables?